# capture data between a repeating string in python

Tags: python, regex, string

I want to extract all data between a repeating string

The text goes like this

```
map report for 0

...................
..............
lot of data in between
.....
......

map report for 1
```

My regex for this is

```
map = re.findall(r"map report for(.+?)\S*\W*map", filestring, re.S)
```

This only returns lines with even numbers after the search string( I presume the odd part is getting included in the preceding even iteration)

any workarounds?

Comment: I would prefer an iterative approach... e.g. splitting the string via 'map report for ' and cycling through tokens.

Comment: If there are several `map report` lines in the file, seems a look-ahead solution will just return the whole file, minus anything before the first one and after the last one (also excluding the last one). Do you want to capture just the non `map report` lines... Or do you want the map lines returned too?

Answer (score 3):

You should consider using `split` instead of `findall` for this.  It seems to be more what you've got in mind:

```
re.split(r'map report for \d+\n', str)
```

This simplifies things greatly in your case.

Answer (score 2):

Your regex *consumes* the `map` word from even matches. You need lookahead:

```
map=re.findall(r"map report for(.+?)\S*\W*(?=map)",filestring,re.S)
```

This way it checks if your match is followed my `map`, but it won't be *consumed*.

Comment: @Bohemian thanks man! RegEx is serious business, no place for lousy wording. Really apperciate it! ;)

Answer (score 0):

The regex I would use would be something like this :

```
(map report for \d+)(.*?)\1
```

The `\1` will keep what you captured first and attempt to match it again at the end, so unlike other approach you can have `map` string in between.

Comment: This would match `"map report for 1BLABLABLAmap report for 1"` which is not what the asker needs. This pattern work for parenthesis or quotation matches, but not this particular case imho.

Comment: @aorcsik I didn't notice that it was 0 then 1. Well then I think Alfe's approach is best.

Comment: There's a rule of thumb that what you can do with 2 string methods shouldn't be done by regex, but I just love regex :)